# Second variable in AngularJS not defined but declared in the same way

Tags: html, angularjs

I extend a web-form, written in HTML and AngularJS. After some registration info is filled into the form, the form must disappear and simultaneously a div with confirmed has to appear. Hiding the form after registration works correct but showing the confirmed div doesn't work because of conformationShown is not defined while this variable is declared in the same manner as formHidden. These variables are declared in the file "labController.js".

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <title>Tony's Pizza - New User Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body ng-controller="labController">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>New User Registration</h1>

        <form ng-hide = "formHidden" class="form-horizontal" name="form" novalidate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Username</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="model.username" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="(form.username.$touched || form.$submitted) && form.username.$error.required">
                        Username is required
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ng-model="model.password" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="(form.password.$touched || form.$submitted) && form.password.$error.required">
                        Password is required
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="model.name" required>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="(form.name.$touched || form.$submitted) && form.name.$error.required">
                        Name is required
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control" ng-model="model.phone" ng-required="true">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="(form.phone.$touched || form.$submitted) && form.phone.$error.required">
                        Phone is required
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input type="email" name="emailAddress" class="form-control" ng-model="model.email" ng-required="true">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="(form.emailAddress.$touched || form.$submitted) && form.emailAddress.$error.required">
                        Email Address is required
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <label>Favorite Pizza</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <select name="favorite" class="form-control" ng-model="model.favorite" ng-required="true">
                        <option>Cheese Pizza</option>
                        <option>Pepperoni Pizza</option>
                        <option>Margherita Pizza</option>
                        <option>BBQ Chicken Pizza</option>
                        <option>Combo Pizza</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="(form.favorite.$touched || form.$submitted) && form.favorite.$error.required">
                        Favorite is required
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div ng-show = "conformationShown" class="alert alert-success">
                Confirmed!
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-5">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit(model)" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" />
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <pre>{{model | json}}</pre>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/registrationService.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/labController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

labController.js

```
app.controller('labController', [
    '$scope', 'registration',
    function ($scope, registration) {

        var formHidden = false;
        var conformationShown = false;

        $scope.formHidden = formHidden;
        $scope.conformationShown = conformationShown;
        $scope.reset = reset;
        $scope.submit = submit;

        reset();

        function submit(model) {
            registration.submit(model).$promise
                .then(function (response) {
                    alert('User registered');
                    $scope.formHidden = true;
                    $scope.conformationShown = true;
                    console.log(conformationShown);

                },
                function (response) {
                    alert('An error occured');
                });
        }

        function reset() {
            $scope.model = {};
        }
    }
]);
```

registrationServices.js

```
angular.module('registrationService', ['ngResource']).
    factory('registration', [
        '$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource('https://reqres.in/api/register',
                {},
                {
                    submit: {
                        method: 'POST'
                    },
                });
        }
    ]);
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',
    [
        'ngResource',
        'registrationService'
    ]
);
```

Comment: But your success alert is _inside_ your form, of course it will be hidden when the form disappears.

Comment: can you create plunkr for the same?

Comment: your "formHidden" is set to true which will hide your form and your success div is inside that form and i guess that will be hidden too den

Comment: Thanks for the answers, the error message was misleading but this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move your success alert outside of your form:

```
<form ng-hide = "formHidden" class="form-horizontal" name="form" novalidate>
    ...
</form>

<div ng-show = "conformationShown" class="alert alert-success">
  Confirmed!
</div>
```

[**Eample Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/G7eOLdKp9CrcDl8uSfgs?p=preview)